# Handling Home button press when inside activity started for result

Tags: android

In my app, I am starting Camera with INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA and starting a [JobScheduler Job](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.Builder#addTriggerContentUri(android.app.job.JobInfo.TriggerContentUri)) to capture new image URIs added and copy the images added to one specific folder.
Now the issue is, if I click home button when camera is running,my job is not getting cancelled and if I start Camera from Camera App,my job is still capturing URIs and copying photos. But I don't want that. Please suggest proper way to handle this.

Comment: "capture new image URIs added and copy the images added to one specific folder" -- there is no guarantee that this will work. There is no requirement for the app that responds to this `Intent` to do something that will allow you to access any photos that the user takes. There is also no guarantee that whatever your job detects is coming from this camera app -- they could be images from some other app. Either use `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` or integrate the camera APIs directly in your app.

Comment: That's why I want to cancel the job if home button is pressed when in Camera activity started for result from my app. Because if I don't cancel the job, my job will keep copying the images even though it is not started by my app.